# Exclude Record using JOIN in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 Tables,

Table MEmployee

```
ID Name
1  Andy
2  Donny
3  Mark
4  John
```

Table Basket

```
ID Name
1  Andy
```

Table Running

```
ID Name
2  Donny
```

And I want to create Soccer table from MEmployee Exclude Basket table and Running. The result like this

Table Soccer

```
ID Name
3  Mark
4  John
```

My Query doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM MEmployee A
INNER JOIN Basket B On A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN Running C ON A.ID = C.ID
WHERE A.ID <> B.ID AND A.ID = C.ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` with `CTE` :

```
with t as (
     select id, name
     from Basket
     union all
     select id, name
     from Running
)

select e.*
from MEmployee e
where not exists (select 1 from t where t.id = e.id);
```

Comment: This is great, even for different column for each table, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `EXCEPT` here:

```
SELECT Name FROM MEmployee
EXCEPT
SELECT Name FROM Basket
EXCEPT
SELECT Name FROM Running;
```

[image]

### Demo